# USB hub connected with multiple network adapters

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, ethernet

I have a 10 port USB hub (link 2) connected to the usb port on a PC. There are 09 USB to giga bit network adapters card (link 1) attached to the USB ports. I set the Ipv4 address for all the individual network cards one by one. They have unique IP addresses and names as in 'network cards' picture.My question is, does computer remembers the names of the network cards in some way? Also, the changed name and IP address cannot be changed to the previous one, as it gives an error that the name is already present, even though it is not visible on the screen.

1. https://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/product/308525/TP-LINK-USB-3-0-Ethernet-adapter-UE300-verkkokortti?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0PWRBhDKARIsAPKHFGi5hg5nrColOgvV6J96YH_etTws_TqD0uK_xCbVu9aB73tbrtThod4aAm-3EALw_wcB
2. https://cdon.fi/kodin-elektroniikka/12-porttinen-usb-2-0-hub-p38968116?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0PWRBhDKARIsAPKHFGjAQ4G3GcXwX9MulosXPZFXQ1fI4Hq68JFaOdDxJHScOJzdrzHP9mgaAnnTEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmG8j.png)

How many ethernet cards can be connected to USB 2.0 / USB 3.0 hub? I have maximum 12 ethernet ports to connect.

My main purpose is to set the names and more importantly the IP addresses only 01 time and after that even if I unplug the cable, the IP addresses remain the same. Also, the operator will not have access to unplug the individual port connected to the USB hub, so that solution is not an option as just unplugging and plugging it back to the USB hub also fixes the issue.

Comment: That sounds like a weird thing to do in the first place. Smells a bit like the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you could explain what you're trying to achieve by connecting a dozen NICs to a single computer, maybe we could come up with a better solution.

Comment: @gronostaj It feels like a XY problem... As he mentions an "operator" this could be some kind of manufacturing situation. Maybe downloading firmware into newly manufactured devices or something like that. But still... There probably is a better solution.

Comment: Well that's not weird to begin with, there are different constraints which does not allow other solutions. I know a couple of other solutions already with different hardware implementation but as I said not feasible for me. What I am trying to do is test Ethernet Switches ports by assigning one IP to each and my one PC/fixture LAN port has a fixed IP. I use iperf to send packet of data through fixed IP port towards 01 port IP and then see if the speed is good enough. And yes, it will be used in manufacturing.

Answer (score 1):

Windows will normally remember network-interfaces across disconnects (if the NIC is a removable device like a USB or Thunderbolt connected NIC) and reboots.

This mechanism is not 100% reliable though.
If you get a Windows update that updates the NIC drivers (or the USB controller drivers) or you get a Windows version upgrade (e.g 21H1 to 21H2)  it is possible they are re-discovered as new interfaces. (Is pretty rare though.)

If you really want to make sure they keep their IP-address you will have to setup DHCP with reservations tied to the NIC's mac-addresses.

P.S. I do hope you realize the performance on these NICs will be awful.